# All Firefox requests get blocked abnormaly long time

Tags: firefox

So here is the thing.
I have many browsers on my computer, however only Firefox takes a while to load any request. Let me enphasize this:  **ANY REQUEST !**
Including loading Javascript files and CSS files. It takes half a minute to load some websites.

I tried deinstalling and reinstalling firefox, removing all extensions, cleaning up the `AppData` files from firefox, but still the same.
OS is Windows 10, Firefox Version is the last (and has been upgraded a few times since the problem appeared without solving it)

Here is an example with Github.com, but i get similar results everywhere :

`Firefox` 3~10s
[image: Firefox takes 3,8s to load github]
Sometime it takes even up to 10 seconds.
[image: Firefox Takes 10s to load github]
And here are the latest useful ressource loaded, I need 15 seconds to load the full page (and only 2.5s on Chrome).
[image]

`Chrome` ~1.6s
[image: Chrome takes 1,6s to load github]

`Brave` ~ 1.9s
[image: Brave takes 1,9s to load github]

Comment: I would temporarily suspend your AV protection and see if that prevents the performance degradation

Comment: Disable all your extensions in Firefox, to test if one of them is the problem.

Comment: @harrymc that was my first thought too, but he did mention *"removing all extensions"* :)